# How to break a number into a list of digits?

Tags: haskell

How to implement a function to break a number into a list of digits?

For example:

```
breakNumber 0 == [0]
breakNumber 1234 == [1,2,3,4]
breakNumber 1000 == [1,0,0,0]
```

And is it possible to implement without using recursion?

Comment: How would you implement this without recursion? If the number can have an arbitrary number of digits, then you can only do this in linear time of the digits.

Comment: Oh yeah, recursion will be used. My question was if it's possible to implement by composing functions from Data.List, so that we no need to use recursion.